# How to Post Status Error Using Angularjs $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new at angular.

i want to post the error message from my server, such as:

[image]

Using angularJS, and this is my code:

```
OwnerList.batch(obArr,function(ob){
            return OwnerList.createItem(cleanOb(ob));
        },4).then(function(){
            $scope.Loading = false;
        },function(response){
            // error function
            console.log(response);
            alert('')
        },function(progress){
            $scope.OwnerListProgress = parseInt(progress * 100);
        });
```

so what do i need to put on error function? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do (I assumed .batch is ajax made by `$http`/`$resource`)

```
alert(response.data.message.value)
```